# How should I install a partition wall perpendicular to a finished exterior wall?

Tags: walls

I wish to install a partition wall with a header made of 2x8s (7 feet long). The header will run perpendicular to ceiling joists. I know the no-nonsense approach is to cut channels in the ceiling drywall and exterior wall drywall to anchor the header and end stud. Unless I am extremely lucky I will have to install some blocking between exterior wall studs to anchor the end wall stud (implies opening a couple spots to install blocking and repairing vapour barrier and drywall).
Is the opening of existing drywall overkill?

Comment: And maybe [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37525/do-i-need-to-remove-existing-drywall-before-framing-an-interior-wall/37530#37530)?

Answer (score 0):

If this is just going to be a partition wall, why do you need the header? There will be no load-bearing issue to address. Thus, no need for a header.

If you want an opening through the partition wall and you want to drop the frame down from the ceiling, just use cripple studs, or put a header just over the opening.

I would strongly consider cutting a channel in the sheetrock. attach the top plate of your wall to the joists above, then build the wall directly under that. Again, no load-bearing issue, no need for a big header to bear the non-existent load. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Craig. I should have addressed a key point in my question. I am installing the header because there is a 7 ft unsupported expanse and a small crack has developed in the ceiling drywall. I suspect it happened when I got new shingles/roof a couple of years ago (weight of shingles, men, movement). The room is 19 ft wide and the only support is a wall 3 ft in from an adjacent exterior wall. So you are right, the wall will be more than a partition wall, it will technically become a bearing wall. Sorry for the confusion. That is why I want to ensure it is well secure at the top and side/end.

Comment: In that case, if it really is needed as a bearing wall, do you have the necessary support under the floor? The crack in the ceiling could just be from movement, not from actual mechanical failure. In any case, if you expect it to bear a load, I'd cut the channel out of the sheetrock, build the wall slightly large (like, 1/16th of an inch, just a hair) and tap it into place with mallets and/or hammers and wood blocks along the bottom of the new wall, so that you have a snug fit and no weak sheetrock bearing any load. The sheetrock is easy to cut and you have taping/mudding to do anyway...